# MySQL Database Connections and Size

Tags: mysql, database

I have look all over the net, and I find varying answers, but had a couple specific questions.

I have a site with about 5400 active members, sort of with a Facebook feel. I have 10 MySQL databases, one database contains a "users" table and a "User_stats" table. The next database contains "photos", and "photo comments", and so on, for blogs, status updates, and so on. Each database has about 4-5 table in it. I think the biggest table has about 250,000 rows in it.

A few years ago I broke them up into different databases because I was hitting limits on my shared host. I now have a virtual server, so I don't have these limits.

I was wondering, as my code is loaded on the page, is it better to open a MySQL connection, close it, open one to a different database, close it, etc, or if I put ALL my tables into one database I would open the connection at the start of the page and close it at the bottom.

Loading a profile page may connect to all 10 databases by the end of the page laoding because of pulling up photos, recent blog entries, user data, and so on.

I am worried about scaling up, and thought if I put them all in 1 database then it will be less taxing than opening and closing so many connections.

What are your thoughts?

Comment: I would say that depends on your database client architecture.  Some languages support pooling, some don't.

Comment: I'm just using PHP and mysql for the site. I am trying to figure out the point of having multiple databases. I thought it would be worse to open and close tables so often, rather than 1 connection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as all the databases are hosted within the same MySql instance, a single client connection may query any/all of the databases.

Example:

```
/*Query #1*/
SELECT FirstName, LastName
FROM userdb.users
WHERE UserID = ?

/*Query #2*/
SELECT PhotoName, Height, Width
FROM photodb.photos
WHERE PhotoID = ?
```

Closing and reopening connections for every database is not the way to go.

Comment: So if I place all the tables in one database and just keep the MySQL connection open for the page and close it at the end of the page it would probably be the best way to go? There's only about 40 tables for the whole site.

Comment: @DerekB There is not real need to move all the tables to a single database. A single connection is the way to go. Depending on the client language you may want to use connection pooling if available.

Comment: I'm using PHP only, so I found a couple articles on the net about using PEAR, but I don't know PEAR at all. Do you happen to have any links that can point me in the right direction? So basically, do I connect to all 10 databases at once, but i can choose the connection for each query?

Comment: @DerekB Once you have a connection is to the mysql *instance*, you can query any table in any database by specifying the database name before the table name. See examples.

Comment: So using your examples, I assume I use a normal mysql_connect(), but how would I set it up with the usernames and passwords for each database? Are you able just to paste some example code with that. And I really do thank you for your help.